# Web service does not work when Application server is upgraded

Tags: web-services, websphere, axis, websphere-8

Current setup -> We have a web service app deployed in Websphere 6.1 and works normally.

Problem -> Does not work when the app is compiled using Websphere 8.5 JRE and then deployed in Websphere 8.5

The odd thing -> When app is compiled using Websphere 6.1 JRE and then deployed in Websphere 8.5 , it works.

The runtime used to generate the web service - Apache Axis

What we want to have is compile it in Websphere 8.5 JRE then deploy it in Websphere 8.5 but we cant get this to work. What seems to be the problem? I was thinking of just re-creating the web service using the new JAX-WS style using annotations, but the problem there is impact on the source codes of the  clients....so its not an option as of now. Only option is no code change and get it to work in Websphere 8.5

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks :)